# Reduce/Fold only some elements

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a file parser that produces a collection of elements all belonging to the same trait. It is similar to the following.

```
trait Data {
  val identifier: String
}

case class Meta(identifier: String, props: Properties) extends Data
case class Complete(identifier: String, contents: Map[String, Any]) extends Data
case class Partial(identifier: String, name: String, value: Any) extends Data

... 

def parse(file: File): Iterator[Data] = ... // this isn't relevant
```

What I am attempting to do is traverse the collection in a functional manner since I am processing a lot of data and want to be as memory conscious as possible. The collection when it is returned from the parse method is a mix of `Complete`, `Meta`, and `Partial` elements. The logic is that I need to pass the `Complete` and `Meta` elements through unchanged, while collecting the `Partial` elements and grouping on the `identifier` to create `Complete` elements.

With just a collection of `Partial` elements (`Iterator[Partial]`), I can do the following:

```
partialsOnly.groupBy(_.identifier)
 .map{ 
   case (ident, parts) => 
     Complete(ident, parts.map(p => p.name -> p.value).toMap)
 }
```

Is there a functional way, somewhat similar to scan that will accumulate elements, but only some elements, while letting the rest through unchanged?

Comment: What about ordering? Can there be a `Meta` or `Complete` between two `Partial`s? Can `Partial` with different ids be intermixed? Is there some way to find out that a particular `Partial` is the last one for a given id (except for waiting till the whole `Iterable` is over)? At what place should the newly-built `Complete` occur in the output Iterator?

Comment: They will be intermixed without any particular order. I can try to add something to the parser to indicate when the last one is sent, but I'm not sure. The parser parses a zip file and the partial due to some data being spread out among many files in the archive. If I know I finished parsing all the partial files in a directory, I could send a tombstone

Comment: The problem is that if the only way to say that particular id is finished with its `Partial`s is to wait till the end of the stream, there is no better implementation than Ethan's because you have to store all the `Partials` till the very end in case one more will arrive. This doesn't sound as a memory-efficient plan.

Comment: Yeah, the situation isn't ideal. Unfortunately, this is a legacy system and the file archive format is the only way to get this data, and cannot be changed. If I can ensure that the ZipInputStream traverses a directory tree in order, then I can send a tombstone at the end of each ident and trigger a grouping operation

Comment: Unless the `Partial`'s are only a small portion of the data, that `groupBy` is going to require a bunch of memory regardless of what you do. You'll likely either need to worry less about memory constraints, or sacrifice functional purity.

Comment: `groupBy` is only required because currently there is no other marker of the end. If there is some marker, I think you can be much more efficient even in a functional way (using something like `fold`). But I agree that often FP purity and performance/memory are at odds (that's why the standard collections are implemented in a mutable way) and in this particular case I'd probably created a custom stateful `Iterator` that would join the data inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `partition` function to split a collection in two based on a predicate.

```
val (partial: List[Data], completeAndMeta: List[Data]) = parse("file").partition(_ match{
  case partial: Partial => true
  case _ => false
})
```

From there, you want to make sure you can process `partial` as a `List[Partial]`, ideally without tripping compiler warnings about type erasure or doing messy casts. You can do this with a call to `collect`, using a function that only accepts `Partial`'s.

```
val partials: List[Partial] = partial.collect(_.match{case partial: Partial => partial}}
```

Unfortunately, when used on an `Iterator`, `partition` may need to buffer arbitrary amounts of data, so isn't necessarily the  most memory efficient technique. If memory management is a huge concern, you may need to sacrifice functional purity. Alternately, if you add some way of knowing when a `Partial` is completed, you can accumulate them in a `Map` via a `foldLeft` and emit the final value as they finish.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion might be functional way to solve your problem:

```
def parse(list: List[Data]): (List[Data], List[Data]) = {
  list match {
     case (x:Partial) :: xs =>
       val (partials, rest) = parse(xs)
       (x :: partials, rest) //instead of creating list, you can join partials here
     case x :: xs =>
       val (partials, rest) = parse(xs)
       (partials, x :: rest)
     case _ => (Nil, Nil)
   }
}

val (partials, rest) = parse(list)
```

Unfortunately, this function is not tail recursive, so it might blow up the stack for longer lists.

You can solve it by using `Eval` from [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eval.html):

```
def parse2(list: List[Data]): Eval[(List[Data], List[Data])] =
    Eval.now(list).flatMap {
      case (x:Partial) :: xs =>
        parse2(xs).map {
          case (partials, rest) => (x :: partials, rest) //instead of creating list, you can join partials here
        }
      case x :: xs =>
        parse2(xs).map {
          case (partials, rest) => (partials, x :: rest)
        }
      case _ => Eval.now((Nil, Nil))
    }

val (partialsResult, restResult) = parse2(longList).value
```

This solution would be safe for the stack because it uses Heap, not Stack.

And here's version, which also groups partials:

```
def parse3(list: List[Data]): Eval[(Map[String, List[Partial]], List[Data])] =
Eval.now(list).flatMap {
  case (x:Partial) :: xs =>
    parse3(xs).map {
      case (partials, rest) =>
        val newPartials = x :: partials.getOrElse(x.identifier, Nil)
        (partials + (x.identifier -> newPartials), rest)
    }
  case x :: xs =>
    parse3(xs).map {
      case (partials, rest) => (partials, x :: rest)
    }
  case _ => Eval.now((Map.empty[String, List[Partial]], Nil))
}
```